# adb screen recording with python

Tags: python, crash, subprocess, adb, screen-recording

hello I'm trying to record the screen of my android with python using adb, but when it executes the line of code with the command to record the screen everything freezes but the recording starts, I think it's because it's waiting for me to stop it but it doesn't execute the next line of code where it says to stop recording because it gets stuck, maybe i'm doing something wrong with subprocess,any help?

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

def record():
    prova = "adb -s " + str(comando) + " shell" + " screenrecord" +" /sdcard/video.mp4"
    provaprocesso = subprocess.Popen(prova, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    provastringa = provaprocesso.communicate(input=None)[0]
    

def stoprecord():
    subprocess.run(["^C"], shell=True, capture_output=True).stdout.decode()
    subprocess.run(["adb" , "-s" , str(comando), "pull" , "/sdcard/video.mp4"], shell=True, capture_output=True).stdout.decode()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    subprocess.run(["adb" , "-s" , str(comando), "shell" , "rm", "/sdcard/video.mp4"], shell=True, capture_output=True).stdout.decode()

record()
time.sleep(3)
stoprecord()
```

i expected it to start recording screen and after time.sleep(3) stop recording

Comment: `^C` it's not a command!

Comment: yes ^C function correctly stops the recording, that's not the problem

Comment: If you think so...

Comment: Try `check=True` to realize that it doesn't work. Furthermore, you are running on your local computer so it won't work even if it were a real command.

Comment: try the code yourself, however if you add print("ok") to the end of the record function you will notice that the program won't print "ok" because it gets stuck at the record command line

Answer (score 0):

You should run

```
adb shell screenrecord --time-limit=3 /sdcard/video.mp4
```